# Why is my vagrant script not running from Windows?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vagrant

I have a Vagrant setup that includes a bash shell provisioning script which runs fine when invoked on a Mac, but which does not work when invoked from a Windows host. The line which works is the first line that calls a python script:

```
foreman run ./manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

And the error given is that python cannot be found:

```
/usr/bin/env python
: File not found
```

I originally thought that this was simply a line ending issue (CRLF v LF), but I checked, and the line endings are correct.

If I SSH into the box, and check /tmp/vagrant-shell (which is where the script is copied to as part of the install) it looks fine. If I use `which python` on the guest VM I get the virtualenv version, which is exactly what I expect. If I check the env vars, `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` are correctly set too.

Given that the script is being copied to the VM and then run from there, it's hard to understand how there can be a difference (other than line endings) between it running from a Windows or OSX host.

Any help gratefully received.

(VM is Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit)

**[UPDATE 1]**

I have run an MD5 hash on the `provision.sh` file, in four separate places:

- Host Windows machine, after `git pull`
- Guest VM, running on windows, post-provision
- Host OSX machine, after `git pull`
- Guest VM, running on OSX, post-provision

And the hash is identical for each - i.e. the file on the VM running on OSX, which works, is a byte-match for the same file running on the VM on Windows.

It's therefore something implicit on the VM as it was set up. But given that the machine is set up using an identical VirtualBox VM on both - perhaps this is a VirtualBox implementation issue?

**[UPDATE 2: workaround]**

By replacing the `./manage.py` with the full `python manage.py` I have got the script to work, which suggests it is a path problem, however I don't have the patience to dig any further. It works, which will do for now.

Comment: Seems duplicated: http://superuser.com/questions/378477/making-usr-bin-env-python-work-on-windows

Comment: So this command is run within the virtual machine, which is the same on both systems (Ubuntu)?

Comment: @iMom0 - no, it's not a duplicate - the script is not running on Windows, it's running on the VM, which is Ubuntu. As part of the Vagrant VM provisioning process the script is copied from the host machine (Windows) to the new VM (into /tmp/vagrant-shell) and then run from the VM.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - yes - the VM is exactly the same, built from the same base image, using the same scripts. Script is running in VM (see previous comment).

Comment: I have checked (using Notepad++) that the line endings in the script are Unix LF chars, and not Windows CRLF chars (which is the obvious potential source).

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown: You should be able to copy the script files from one to another and do a compare on them to find the differences.

Comment: as far as i can tell they are byte-copies of each other. that's the mystery...

Comment: I have MD5 hashed the files on each machine (on both host and guest), and they are identical, but one runs and the other doesn't. VirtualBox issue?

Comment: to make sure windows CR are removed you can run the following command `sudo sed -i -e 's/\r$//' manage.py`